# QGIS crashes after removeChildNode() Called

Tags: table-of-contents, qgslayertree

I have followed QGIS examples on how to move layers on TOC by inserting and removing nodes. I tried the QGIS documentation approach, which clones a node then reinserts it and removes the first one as well as other approaches like inserting all the nodes I want first and then deleting all the others but each time QGIS crashes randomly. Right now I am using QGIS 3.22.9. Has anyone else issues trying to reproduce the documentation's approach on moving layers around the TOC? Let's say I tried it on a project with more than ten layers.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue by adding this method to my script (forcing script to be executed by the main thread):

```
def flags(self):
    return(QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading)
```